# DataTable Trickle down duplicate values to last duplicate to fill with most recent data

Tags: c#, excel, linq, datatable, duplicates

Using C# and whatever can run in a windows Forms desktop application get a DataTable to trickle down duplicate values to last duplicate to fill with most recent data and remove all other duplicates. Keep non duplicates as well.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("First Name");
dt.Columns.Add("LAST NAME");
dt.Columns.Add("STATE");
dt.Columns.Add("ADDRESS");
dt.Columns.Add("ZIP CODE");
dt.Columns.Add("TELEPHONE NUMBER");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "John", "Hill", "NY", "5 Street" , "", "");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "John", "Hill", "NY", "11 East" , "15543", "", "(846)456-7655");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "John", "Hill", "NY", "", "98777", "", "");
dt.Rows.Add(4, "John", "Hill", "NY", "34 West", "", "", "");
dt.Rows.Add(5, "Mary", "Frey", "IL", "45 South", "", "", "765655-45444");
```

Result would be:

```
|4 | "John" | "Hill" | "NY" | "34 West" | "98777" | "15543" | "(846)456-7655"|
|5 | "Mary" | "Frey" | "IL" | "45 South" | "" | "" | "765655-45444"|
```

So trickle down data to fill empty spots

```
|1| |3| |4|
| |2| | | |
|5| |6|7| |
___________
 5 2 6 7 4
```

1. DataTable has dynamical columns length but will always have "First Name", "Last Name" and "State".
2. First Name, Last Name and State are compared for duplicates.(would be nice to have these dynamic for the user to change if they want)
3. Last index of duplicate values trump all other values (we want to keep the latest values).
4. If last index value has nulls or empty string get previous duplicate value if exist for each column cell. (Basically last duplicate keeps all the data, if there isn't data in a cell find data from another duplicate to fill it in. This could come from multiple duplicates to fill all the data up).
5. Keep non duplicates.

**Current code to implement into:**

Basically build a string using the below

```
KeyWordsSelect : is what the user select columns to compare
excelColumns : is the rest of the columns without user selected columns.
```

How I am doing the select statement:

```
string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [{1}]", excelColumns, First_sheet);
```

Here is the code:

```
//Connect to file
            using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'", openFileDialog1.FileName)))
            {

                excel_con.Open(); // Open reader
                First_sheet = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); //get first sheet name

                //Get columns in Excel  Sheet
                DataTable dtColumns = excel_con.GetSchema("Columns", new string[4] { null, null, First_sheet, null });
                string excelColumns = string.Empty;

                //Keywords these are what the user wants to compare and have to be a ccolumn already in the sheet
                string KeyWordsSelect = string.Empty;
                foreach (object item in KeyWords_List.Items) //Dont inluded main comparisons
                {
                    KeyWordsSelect += "[" + item.ToString() + "],";
                }
                KeyWordsSelect = KeyWordsSelect.TrimEnd(',');

                //Get column names minus user selected columns
                bool IsKeyword;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtColumns.Select("", "ORDINAL_POSITION ASC"))
                {
                        IsKeyword = false;
                        foreach (object item in KeyWords_List.Items) //Inluded rest of columns without user seleceted columns
                        {
                            if (dr["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() == item.ToString())
                            {
                                IsKeyword = true;
                            break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!IsKeyword) //Dont included keyword columns
                        {
                            excelColumns += "[" + dr["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() + "] AS [" + dr["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() + "],"; // dynamicaly add columns
                        }
                }

                dtColumns.Clear();  //Clear and free up memory
                excelColumns = excelColumns.TrimEnd(','); // remove trailing comma
                //Get columns

                //Filter data
                string SelectStament = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [{1}]", excelColumns, First_sheet);  //KeyWordsSelect are columns the user slected, ExcelColums are the remaining columns from the sheet
                OleDbCommand SelectStatment = new OleDbCommand(SelectStament, excel_con); // select content from Excel
                OleDbDataReader Excel_Data = SelectStatment.ExecuteReader();

                if (Excel_Data.HasRows) //Has data
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); //create new table
                    dataTable.Load(Excel_Data); // set data from OleDB
                }
                Excel_Data.Close(); // Close data
                excel_con.Close(); // Close connection

            }
```

Comment: Which of the columns takes precedence when comparing? First Name, Last Name, or State? For example if there is John Hill, and after that Jane Hill, which name do I keep, John or Jane? Same question for last name.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake in the example. I corrected my example: Last Name, First Name and State have to match to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Dynamic columns are not supported on a `DataTable`. Each column will need to be defined before you can add a row with that new column. I.e. your ID column specified in your `dt.Rows.Add` param list will fail because it's not a column in the `DataTable`. More specifically, you'll get a `Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.` error for any row insert with more cells than columns. However you can specify fewer values than defined columns, the remaining will just be a default value.

Comment: I corrected the missed ID column. Yes not dynamic column but  which column to compare would be dynamic.

Comment: @Zealous see my answer below,  it trickles down the latest value as described. Please let me know if this is not what you intended and I'll be happy to continue to help, or mark it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you added a `linq` tag to this question, I'll give you a `linq` answer. As long as the columns are defined in the table (no dynamic row-by-row column length difference), the following will work. Assuming that the first 4 columns are ID, FirstName, LastName, and State you can have an arbitrary number of additional columns.

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("First Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("LAST NAME");
    dt.Columns.Add("STATE");
    dt.Columns.Add("ADDRESS");
    dt.Columns.Add("ZIP CODE");
    dt.Columns.Add("TELEPHONE NUMBER");
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John", "Hill", "NY", "5 Street", "");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "John", "Hill", "NY", "11 East", "15543", "(846)456-7655");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "John", "Hill", "NY", "", "98777", "");
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "John", "Hill", "NY", "34 West", "", "");
    dt.Rows.Add(5, "Mary", "Frey", "IL", "45 South", "", "765655-45444");


    dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .GroupBy(d => new 
            { 
                First = d.Field<String>("First Name"), 
                LastName = d.Field<String>("Last Name"), 
                State = d.Field<String>("State")
            })
        .Select(d => d.OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<Int32>("ID")))
        .Select(d => new { 
            Latest = d.First(), 
            Columns = Enumerable
                .Range(4, d.First().Table.Columns.Count - 4)
                .Select(r => d.Select(x => new {Name = d.First().Table.Columns[r].ColumnName, Data= x.Field<String>(r)}).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Data))) })
        .Select(d =>
            {
                d.Columns.Where(x => x.Any()).ToList().ForEach(c => d.Latest[c.First().Name] = c.First().Data);
                return d.Latest;
            });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Carlo, I having difficulty implementing that code. I added the code that I am using to create the select statement to the original question.

Basically build a string using the below strings:

KeyWordsSelect : is what the user select columns to compare
excelColumns : is the rest of the columns without user selected columns.

How I am doing the select statement: 
string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [{1}]", excelColumns, First_sheet);

Comment: The answer above should fit just fine in your code, right after you finish loading your DataTable (dataTable.Load(Excel_Data);). replace `dt` with `dataTable` and you're off to the races. By the way the following line should replace the for loop: `var KeyWordsSelect = $"[{String.Join("],[", KeyWords_List)}]";`